# Data passing with reusable popup VC function

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass data from a pop-up VC to the parent VC using reusable function to present the pop-up and get the result. I have tried using the closure method with a function variable in the pop-up, I get an error "UIViewController has no member 'onSave' (function variable).  Any help would be appreciated.  thx

I have used delegates and segues but would like to avoid so one function can be present the pop-up and collect the choices for many instances.

```
// Parent VC
class a2ExpenseAddViewController: UIViewController {
@IBAction func selectEtype(_ sender: Any) {
    popTitle = "Expense Types"//global var
    popMessage = "Select type below or add new" // global var
    menuPopup(choices: eTypes){ result in guard let result = else{
        return
        }
        self.eType.setTitle(result, for: .normal)        
    print("popChoice=",result)
    }
}

extension UIViewController { 

func menuPopup (choices: [String], completion: @escaping (_   choice: String?)  -> ()) {
let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let goto = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup")
popChoices = choices
// Error below here - UIViewController has no member 'onSave'
goto.onSave = { (data: String) -> () in 
choice = data
}
self.present(goto, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Popup VC
PopupViewController: UIViewController,.. // storyboard id is 'popup'
var onSave: ((_ data: String) -> ())?

@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    popChoice = choice.text!
    onSave?(popChoice)
    dismiss(animated: true)    }
```

I expect to assign result via onSave(data) to a button title.
I get an error "UIViewController has no member 'onSave' (function variable).

Comment: you need to cast the `ViewController` to specific type after instantiating. So it should go like `let goto = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup") as? PopupViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the ViewController to specific class type after instantiation.

```
let goto = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup") as? PopupViewController
```

Then you should be able to do this

```
goto.onSave = { (data: String) -> () in 
choice = data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse. This works to eliminate the error and produce the correct value at the function level (choice is defined). However, I'm still having problems getting the choice back to the Parent VC.  So menuPopup returns without producing a result. Neither the setTitle or print statement are executed.  Any ideas?  Thanks again

Comment: You are not invoking the completion block at all in your code. So, you need to replace `goto.onSave = { ... }` with `goto.onSave = completion`